# Como substituir os pontos de interrogação(?) por barras(/)?

Tags: php, javascript

Como faço para substituir os pontos de interrogação dos parametros na url por barras ? Como por exemplo, passar meudominio/inicio.php?page=2 para meudominio/inicio/page/2.

Um pedaço do meu código:

```
if (isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}
else
{
    $page = 1;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#next").click(function() {
    page = page + 1;

    location.href = "?page="+page+"";
});
```

Comment: isso se faz com o arquivo .htaccess do apache, procura por url_rewrite que encontra bastante coisa.

Comment: Como o @NeuberOliveira disse, e realmente no .htaccess . Aqui tem um bom começo para você https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: Boas, Uma das soluções é termos URL's amigavies, espero que o seguinte seja útil para te explicar como isso se faz: [http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-urls-amigaveis](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-urls-amigaveis)